# Spring MVC 3.1, Controller do not works

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, spring-mvc, netbeans, annotations

We have a Sprint Project with annotations. The web.xml is exactly equals to http://pastebin.com/cKDPaMJQ, the dispatcher-servlet has been copied to http://pastebin.com/Sn904ie9.

The Controller source is below:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package br.gov.rj.pge.lawsuit.controller.submissioncontroller;

import br.gov.rj.pge.lawsuit.dao.submissiondao.SubmissionDao;
import br.gov.rj.pge.lawsuit.domain.submission.Submission;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 *
 * @author SANTOSML
 */
@Controller
public class SubmissionController {

    private SubmissionDao dao;

    @RequestMapping("/save_submission")
    public ModelAndView saveSubmission(Submission submission) {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("index");
        try {
            dao.save(submission);
            view.addObject("message", "Ok");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            view.addObject("message", "Error");
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

This controller is not usefull, but we think this shold works. however, when we try to access "/save-submission" or "save_submission.html" url in the application, the server returns a 404 error. Apparently, the method return, that references an existent jsp (index.jxp), is being ignored and the 404 page has the message "/ElectronicLawsuit/WEB-INF/jsp/save_submission.jsp", that do not exists.

We is using Netbeans and Tomcat 7.

Somebody can help us, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the context path of the app, and what's the exact and complete URL you tried?

Comment: @JB Nizet Excuse-me! The url of this application is "localhost:8084/ElectronicLawsuit/" (according the Netbeans) and the tried url is "localhost:8084/ElectronicLawsuit/save_submission" or "localhost:8084/ElectronicLawsuit/save_submission.html". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

where have you defined `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your spring-config file to support annotation driven controllers ?

Comment: Thank you very much! Whe had just try it! We put this element in the dispacher-servlet.xml. But, it did not work! What is the correct file to define it, please?

Comment: yeah its need to be defined in dispatcher-servlet.xml only. Can you please share the server logs when you hit the url ?

Comment: Apache do not wrote any log for this situation! Its normal? Thanks!

Comment: debug logs enabled ? Also you have index.jsp at location /WEB-INF/jsp/ ?

Comment: if you are not able to see logs, can you add a debug point and check if saveSubmission methid is getting called when you hit url localhost:8084/ElectronicLawsuit/save_submission.html ?

Comment: I created a breakpoint. The method is never called. The /WEB-INF "/jsp/index.jps" exists. How I may to check if debub logs is enabled?

Comment: u can share your log4j file, also if you can share your maven dependencies?